# Redirect all .php to same name + prefix

Tags: .htaccess

Working code for one file:
RewriteRule ^cookiestatement.php/?$ /m_cookiestatement.php [R,L]

I would like all php-files be redirect to its own filename but with the prefix m_

I can make it work for one file, but need it to do it for all .php files

RewriteRule ^cookiestatement.php/?$ /m_cookiestatement.php [R,L]

so 
index.php --> m_index.php
contact.php --> m_contact.php
etc...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to use a regular expression to match the requests, not a literal string. So something like the following, though you probably still have to adjust it to your setup:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond m_%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php/?$ /m_$1.php [R=302]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).